# Homophones in Proto-Germanic

Tags: historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, sound-change, proto-germanic, reconstruction

Does anyone know reconstructed homophones in Proto-Germanic or where I could look them up? I am interested in clear homophones, not polysemes.

Comment: The difference between homophone and polyseme is fleeting and depends on you or much rather the original speaker recognizing the connection. Which is kinda subjective. *habjana has two etymology sections but both go to the same PIE roothttps://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/habjaną *wesana goes to two different roots but that might just change if we could project farther back https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/wesaną arguably Ger. "er is(s)t" (he is/eats) shows the same homophone, still, which might be a bit more than coincidence ("es ist ..."?)

Comment: Yes, there's truth to that. But I am sure that there are always cases where you can say with certainty that something is not a polyseme.  
I hope I understood you correctly, Ger. *essen, isst* is derived from /*etaną and if you look at the conjugation table of /*wesaną ‘(to) feast’ (which isn't suppletive unlike ‘(to) be’) there seems to be no connection to *essen*.
  
btw, How do I prevent the single asterisk from setting my text to italics?

Comment: That is a good hint that *wesaną is a homophone. So, that's ideal.

Comment: Well, as I said, I find it very hard to decide. The formation of the strong verb conjugation for "to be" surely doesn't invite saying just about anything with certainty. I supposed there is a reason that the 3. p. s. conjugation for both *wesana is basically the same. Then "essen" was just an off side remark because I always find it funny, and to be honest I don't know a particular reason *et- should become Ger. "es-". On the other hand, the conjugations for *wesana 1 and 2 are not exactly homophone at all.

Comment: That's the normal High German consonant shift. Spirantization/Affrication of Germanic voiceless stops is the essential feature of High German.  
*t > /t͡s, s̟~s̻~s̪/ ⟨z⟩ > /t͡s, s/ ⟨z, ß, s(s)⟩.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what caused it. Maybe wesana was driving the shift. Also, dialectal northern "dit" ("das" - that, the [neuter]) "et", "wat" etc. seemingly retained the /t/ but I never heard "etten". "bitte", "bieten", "Pot", "beten" "Knete" never participated (or were borrowed later or had th instead, I only checked *bito "bitte")

Comment: Ah, that is easily explained. *Dit* and *dat* can only be found in areas where the High German consonant shift didn't take place or only to a very limited extent (as in the Rhineland).  
*Dit* and *dat* are instances of Low German substrate or in the Rhineland West-Middle German substrate.  
*eten* is the correct Low German form of *essen* (only one t, because the fricatives that resulted from the High German consonant shift closed the previously open syllable –potentially by gemination at first).

Comment: *bieten* is from *beudan*, *Pot* is Low German, *beten* is from *bedan*, *Knete* is from *knedan*.

Comment: Here is a short list of Low Saxon words (I decided to use the IPA for some vowels, where I didn't find the normal spelling conventions appropriate.

Comment: nds. */e:/ten, w/e:/ten, ik, dat, maken, b/e:/den , b/ɛɪ̯/den, bidden, b/i:/ten, F/ɔʊ̯/t, m/œʏ̯/ten, gr/oː/t*

Comment: hd. *essen, wissen, ich, das, machen, beten, bieten, bitten, beißen, Fuß, müssen, groß*

Comment: So, this should show you, if you've never heard *eten* etc. that's just because the old dialects are endangered. The High German standard language has spread into the north.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87060/discussion-between-tobiornottobi-and-vectory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set wiktionary's search to reconstruction namespace and search for

> Germanic "etymology 2"

[try if the link retained the settings](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=Germanic+%22etymology+2%22&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&searchengineselect=mediawiki&advancedSearch-current=%7B%22namespaces%22%3A%5B118%5D%7D&ns118=1)

#### A few examples

> #### *hringaz
>
> 1. ring, circle; curve.
>    From earlier *hrengaz (compare Proto-Finnic loanword *rengas), from Proto-Indo-European *(s)krengʰ-, extended nasalized form of Proto-Indo-European *(s)ker- (“to turn, bend”).
> 2. sound, ring.
>    From Proto-Indo-European *(s)kreg-, *(s)kArg-, *(s)kArk- (“to caw, crow, croak, pipe, shout”). Cognate with Lithuanian krañkti (“to caw, cough, croak”).
>    https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hringaz
>
> #### *fōdrą
>
> 1. fodder.
>    From Proto-Indo-European *peh₂- (“to protect, guard, graze, feed”). Possibly cognate with Latin pānis (“bread, food”).
> 2. sheath.
>    From Proto-Indo-European *peh₂- (“to protect, guard, graze, feed”) +‎ *-þrą (“tool suffix”).
>    https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/f%C5%8Ddr%C4%85
>
> #### *aldiz
>
> 1. age, generation; lifetime.
>    From *alaną +‎ *-þiz.
> 2. human being; person; man.
>    From *alaną +‎ *-þiz.
>    https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/aldiz
>
> #### *armaz
>
> 1. arm.
>    From Proto-Indo-European *h₂ermos, *h₂ŕ̥mos.
> 2. poor, miserable; pitiful, pitiable.
>    From Proto-Indo-European *h₁erm- (“poor, ill”). Cognate with Hittite  (erman, “sickness”). Alternatively[1], from Pre-Germanic *h₃orbʰmos, with loss of -b- before -m-, from Proto-Indo-European *h₃erbʰ-; compare the Norse variant aumr, as from *arbmaz with no loss of -b-, which mirrors the dissimilation of Old Norse haustr from *harbistaz.
>    https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/armaz

Comment: Good answer! But would you mind adding some examples, in case Wiktionary changes their interface and kills your link?

Comment: I tried but meanwhile it became community wiki so I probably need to remove my commentary

Comment: "it became community wiki so I probably need to remove my commentary"  What do you mean by that?

Comment: You can see previous edits if you click "revs" I believe